# fetch email ids from user input

Tags: php, email

i have a form where user can either input email ids like

```
someone@somewhere.com,anyone@anywhere.com
```

OR

```
someone@somewhere.com anyone@anywhere.com
```

I'm using PHP for scripting i would like to have the email ids extracted!

I'm expecting some cool solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi guys thanks for your patient and speedy replies but 
i found out a way i'll accept this only when you confirm it has no bugs.ie no replies for a day

```
<?php
$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", 
           "someone@somewhere.com,anyone@anywhere.com,",-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($keywords);
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => someone@somewhere.com
    [1] => anyone@anywhere.com
)
```

it was omitting even the extra comma at the end. even if i added more space
waiting for your replies!

Answer (score 2):

You could use preg_split(), but to be honest, the simplest solution would be to convert all spaces to commas (or vice versa) and then explode by that.

```
$emails = explode(",", str_replace(" ", ",", $email_string));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = "someone@somewhere.com,anyone@anywhere.com";
$emails = explode(",", $input);
if(count($emails) == 1) {
    $emails = explode(" ", $input);
}

print_r($emails);

/* output:

Array
(
    [0] => someone@somewhere.com
    [1] => anyone@anywhere.com
)

*/
```

Comment: This works as long as there isn't a `quoted-string` containing a space or comma in the [`local-part` of the address](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.4.1) (the part before the `@`).

Comment: It's pretty rare.  But if you're writing an [MUA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_user_agent), you need to cover those cases.  The poster probably isn't and hence doesn't.

Comment: Yeah. I can't imagine anyone actually using an email like that though. Can you imagine telling your friends that your email is "quotation-mark awesome guy quotation-mark at example dot com"? I assume someone has found a use for it though...